# How or where can I get separate notes of an instrument for playback in my application?

Tags: audio, mp3, midi

I am looking to create a music creation application, and would like to allow the user to play the individual notes of an instrument. Is there a place online where I can find individual sound files that I may playback for each note, or is there a way of programmatically "generating" each pitch? I am not concerned with sound quality at this point in my development.

EDIT: I am still in the early stages of development. I want the app to be browser based, using Javascript or something similar. A Linux development environment, if that is of relevance at all. The notes will be played via an on-screen interface.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific. What operating system are you using? What programming language? How are the notes to be played: via a MIDI keyboard? via an onscreen keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of places online to find sampled instruments. If you're not concerned about sound quality, some free soundfonts will most likely do the job.

For example, this site http://soundfonts.homemusician.net/ has pianos, basses, guitars, horn etc. (Google "[free sf2](http://www.google.com/search?q=free%20sf2&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)" for more)

There are plenty of ways to generate (aka synthesise) tones as well.

Answer (score 1):

The University of Iowa's Electronic Music Studios has a very nice and complete [archive of sampled instruments](http://theremin.music.uiowa.edu/), with one musical note per file. You should also check out [freesound](http://www.freesound.org), though that is a much more general-purpose sample sharing site.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind MIDI files, you can get a free MIDI software piano and create your own files:  C.mid, C#.mid, D.mid, etc.

Here's one with a quirky interface but there are many more:

http://download.cnet.com/MidiPiano/3000-2133_4-10542342.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to simply output MIDI messages to the synth built-in to every computer.  No need to create MIDI files or use extra sound fonts.

You didn't mention what language you are using, so it is hard to suggest ways to get started.    In all cases though, you'll want to read up a bit on what MIDI actually is.

Basically, MIDI is nothing but control data, commonly used with synthesizers.  At a basic level, there are note-on, and note-off messages.  There are many other kinds of messages too, such as pitch bend, control change, etc.  MIDI supports 16 "channels", which are sent all down the same line, just with a different identifier.

A good utility (on Windows) for debugging MIDI messages (and getting a better idea of the protocol in general!) can be found here:  http://www.midiox.com/